# AES Encryption in C#, Decryption in Java

Tags: c#, java, aes

I referred to [this source](http://forums.asp.net/t/1331002.aspx/1) about the AES Encryption/Decryption and use the code in my C# project

I encrypted a text in C# with all the parameters defined by me. In my school project, the text is sent to the Android client, decrypted and displayed on the screen. I searched for the Java AES decryption but none uses such parameters, like in C#, as the key is generated automatically. I also saw some similar questions here but still haven't got the solution. 
Can anyone help me with this problem ?

Comment: Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jce/JCERefGuide.html

Comment: First you need to choose a mode. The choice of mode is crucial for the security of your project, and depends on your requirements. Do you need: 1. random read access? 2. Random write access/incremental updates? 3. Use a single key multiple times? 4. Authenticated encryption? Once you've chosen a mode that fits your needs, one can figure out how to implement it in both languages.

Answer (score 0):

In sun.security there are some classes that related to encrypt and decrypt, some of the are AES related (like AES128/256),
take a look at this **[article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.htmlhttp://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html)**

Answer (score 0):

follow this article it is very good :
          http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/304187/how-to-create-password-encrypt-decrypt-in-csharp